# GNOME lockscreen disable Quick Settings

Tags: gnome, screen-lock, gdm

I don't like the idea of being able to toggle the radios or connect to a Wi-Fi network on the login/lock screen. Thus I would like to disable the "cards" of the Quick Settings menu, but apart from some extensions (which obviously don't work on the lockscreen) I could not find a way to to this.

So is there a way to accomplish my goal? I would also be fine with disabling the Quick Settings menu (on the lockscreen) altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an extension for Gnome 45 which will hide the top panel on the GDM login and lock screen.

Install it manually as a system-wide extension.

https://github.com/surfinky/gnome-login-hide-panel

Hope this helps.